# Mudblazor not able to justify items, one to the left and one to the right

Tags: flexbox, blazor, mudblazor

I’ve looked through all of the “Justify Content” section of the Mudblazor docs but I’m just not getting it. I have two buttons that sit above a MudTable. I want one button to be all the way to the left and the other all the way to the right. I’ve tried a couple versions but based on the docs this is what I came up with but it’s not working. See picture.

I’m also going to need to do the same thing inside of my MudTable’s ToolBarContent section. There I want to have a badge to the far left and the Search textbox to the far right. I figure I can apply the same code in the ToolBarContent section as I can for the button above my MudTable.

[image]

```
<div class="d-flex justify-space-between flex-grow-1 gap-4">
    <MudButton Variant=" Variant.Filled" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.EditNote"
               Size="Size.Small" Class="ml-auto">Item Count</MudButton>

    <MudButton Variant=" Variant.Filled" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.EditNote"
               Size="Size.Small" Class="ml-auto">View History</MudButton>
</div>


<MudTable Items="@list" Dense="true" Hover="true" Bordered="true" Striped="true" CustomHeader="true" HeaderClass="mud-table-header"
          Filter="new Func<Dependent,bool>(FilterFunc1)" @bind-SelectedItem="selectedDependent">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString" Placeholder="Search Last Name" Immediate="true" DebounceInterval="2" Clearable="true" Style="width: 300px;align-self:end"
                      Variant="Variant.Outlined" Margin="Margin.Dense"
                      Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
    </ToolBarContent>
```

UPDATE

```
<MudGrid Width="100%">
    <MudItem Width="50%">
        <MudButton Variant=" Variant.Filled" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.EditNote"
                   Size="Size.Small" Class="ml-auto">Item Count</MudButton>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem Width="50%">
        <MudButton Variant=" Variant.Filled" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.EditNote"
                   Size="Size.Small" Class="ml-auto">View History</MudButton>
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
```

Comment: Use a grid with two columns?

Comment: Tried the "justify-content-between" but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis tried the MudGrid and I may not have it done correctly but see my "UPDATE" in the original post. I tried that code but it moved both buttons to the far left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close with your original snippet. The `ml-auto` on your buttons is pushing them to the right. Remove those classes and you should be fine.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-space-between"> 
  <MudButton 
    Variant="Variant.Filled" 
    StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.EditNote"
    Size="Size.Small">
    Item Count
  </MudButton>

  <MudButton 
    Variant="Variant.Filled" 
    StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.EditNote"
    Size="Size.Small">
    View History
  </MudButton>
</div>
```

I have also simplified the classes on the container.

The `flex-grow-1` class is redundant, unless the container itself is a flex item.

The `gap-4` class only has an effect when the buttons are adjacent - which will only happen on extremely narrow viewports.

Working example: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mOGRlclKGKfRGqNs

#### Edit

An alternative approach without using justify is to apply `ml-auto` to your right button. The left button will naturally want to stick to the left of the container, and the right button will be pushed as far right as possible by the margin.

```
<div class="d-flex"> 
  <MudButton 
    Variant="Variant.Filled" 
    StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.EditNote"
    Size="Size.Small">
    Item Count
  </MudButton>

  <MudButton 
    Variant="Variant.Filled" 
    StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.EditNote"
    Size="Size.Small"
    class="ml-auto">
    View History
  </MudButton>
</div>
```

The downside with this alternative approach is that it only works when you want to push the right-most item to the end - i.e. it is an alternative to flexbox `justify-*` only when n = 2.

Learning and using the different flexbox container properties is arguably a better approach in general, although there's nothing wrong with using the `ml-auto` trick when you have this kind of layout.

Updated example: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckcHPGPKwKCsPyNK

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this is the Grid approach: it's similar to most framework's grid systems.

- `py=2` Add some vertical padding to the grid.
- `xs=6` Split it into two for all window sizes.
- `d-flex justify-start` and `d-flex justify-end` flex it and set the justification
- `ps-3` and `pe-3`  pad the start or end

```cs
<MudGrid Class="py-2">
    <MudItem xs="6" Class="d-flex justify-start ps-3" >
        <MudButton Variant=" Variant.Filled" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.EditNote"
                   Size="Size.Small" >Item Count</MudButton>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="6" Class="d-flex justify-end pe-3">
        <MudButton Variant=" Variant.Filled" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.EditNote"
                   Size="Size.Small"> View History</MudButton>
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
```

[image]